# Git merge overwrites my changes after merge gone wrong

Tags: git, merge

We have, among others following git branches:
 - feature branches
 - beta branch
 - development

I had to take a branch of a colleauge who left the company. This branch has been waiting a long time for internal review and testing and thus lacks by far behind development. But the branch has been merged to branch beta in the past.

Now reportedly following happend:
Someone erroneus merged beta to development.
Another one reverted that merge.

But now when I try to merge development into the feature branch, development overwrites the changes of the feature branch.

Also I can't merge the feature branch to development. Git states that those branches are already merged. But the changes of the feature branch aren't in development.

Help would be much appreciated. I'm not at all looking forward to merge around 1000 changes in 30 classes manually :(

Comment: I wonder if you have the strategy to allow a force update, which is not allowed in our team. If you do, you could reset the development branch to the commit before the unexpected merge and `git push -f` to update the remote development branch. Our team also forbids any non-fast-forward merge to the main branch. In the local, one could do anything as he/she likes. But it's only allowed to put any of the commits to the main branch by an ff-only merge or a cherry pick or a rebase. Since we use Gerrit, every commit/patch set, updated, submitted or abandoned, can be found in the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One workaround would be to:

- clone the repo in a temporary local repo,
- still *locally*, do an interactive rebase of development in order to remove the merge commit from `beta`) and the revert commit,
- merge `develop` to `master`,

Then in the local repo (the current one, where no rebase took place):

- add the temporary repo as a remote
- fetch and then cherry pick the merge commit to the `master` branch
- finally, do a `git merge --ours develop`, in order to record in `master` a merge commit (without changing any file, since the actual merge was cherry-picked just before)
- push (no force push needed, since you only added new commits)

Comment: Hi!
That sounds promising. I will discuss this with my colleagues. And hopefully we get that workaround running.

Comment: We were able to solve the situation by cherry picking the few commits from the feature branch.